# Auctex: robust way to align a tabular with nested groups

Tags: emacs

I’m using in emacs/AucTex the following code to align a tabular-like environment:

```
  (defun align-environment ()
    "Apply align to the current environment only."
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (LaTeX-mark-environment)
      (align (point) (mark))))
```

to automatically go from:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello & foo\\
    Bye & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

to

```
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello & foo \\
    Bye   & x
  \end{ZX}
```

which helps a lot with readability. Unfortunately, this is higly non-robust to groups/environments. For instance, aligning:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello & foo \\
    Bye \begin{pmatrix}A & B   \\ C & D\end{pmatrix} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

would give me:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello                & foo \\
    Bye \begin{pmatrix}A & B   \\ C & D\end{pmatrix} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

instead of

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello                                            & foo \\
    Bye \begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

Similarly, this:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello & foo \\
    Bye {A & B \\ C & D} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

would align to:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello  & foo \\
    Bye {A & B   \\ C & D} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

instead of

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    Hello                & foo \\
    Bye {A & B \\ C & D} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

and I’m not even mentionning stuff like:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    A & Hello         & foo \\
    {B \\ C} & Bye
    \begin{pmatrix}
      A & B \\
      C & D
    \end{pmatrix} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

that aligns to

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    A             & Hello & foo \\
    {B                          \\ C}      & Bye
    \begin{pmatrix}
      A           & B           \\
      C           & D
    \end{pmatrix} & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

instead of

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    A        & Hello          & foo \\
    {B \\ C} & Bye
               \begin{pmatrix}
                 A & B \\
                 C & D
               \end{pmatrix}  & x
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

or, for the last example,

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    A & B
  \end{ZX} = & % RESET ALIGN
  \begin{ZX}
    A & B
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

is already well aligned, and should NOT be turned into:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{ZX}
    A        & B
  \end{ZX} = & % RESET ALIGN
  \begin{ZX}
    A        & B
  \end{ZX}
\end{align}
```

Would it be possible to make the align function more robust?

**Bonus:** I would also love to be able to comment stuff like `% RESET ALIGN` in order to reset the whole alignment.